# PHP cURL response issue

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm using the below curl request which returns a XML structured response. The response however seems wrong (first line: string(744978) "<?xml etc). I normally json_decode it, however that does not seem to work. Is this an issue in the endpoint or am I doing something wrong? I would like to convert the response to an array so I can store it in a database.

REQUEST

```
$url = 'url';   
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

RESPONSE
[image: begin]

[image: end]

Comment: You are asking an endpoint, that delivers XML, not JSON. You either need to process the response as XML (e.g., with https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php ) or ask the endpoint to send JSON, if it supports it (e.g., with an additional `Accept` HTTP header).

Comment: Wonderful! This is exactly what I needed. Solution was to convert the XML to JSON via:

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
curl_close($ch);

Comment: `string(744978) "` was this from using something like `var_dump` to output the results to the screen or actually in the response?

Answer (score 1):

function xml_to_json_feed() {

```
$url = 'http://x';  
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

curl_close($ch);
```

return $array;
}

Answer (score 0):

use this function for result like

```html
$url = 'url';   
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = api_result($result);
curl_close($ch);

 function api_result($result){
        $plainXML = $this->mungXML($result);
        $arrayResult = json_decode(json_encode(SimpleXML_Load_String($plainXML, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)), true);
        return $arrayResult;
    }

 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: please also put this function